# php autoload perfomance

Tags: php, xdebug

Even if use

```
spl_register_autoload( function( $class )
{
    $file = '/path/to/lib/' . $class;
    require_once( $file );
    return class_exists( $class, false );
} );
```

xdebug shows that total self cost for this closure (19%) is a little less than its inclusive cost (25%). And it's 10 times higher then PDO's execute() (2%).

Why does it takes so much time?

Comment: Seems xdebug takes included file's code as closure's code. That's why such results. I've found it out when modified included files. As I 'm using APC, execution time has been increased. It has affected closure's self cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems xdebug takes included file's code as closure's code. That's why are such results.
I've found it out when modified included files.
As I 'm using APC, execution time has been increased. It has affected closure's self cost.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an autoloader then you should NOT use _once functions becouse they are slow. Use the require($file) (it seems to me this is wrong in your code becouse you are requiring the $class which is not a file).

Comment: $class was a mistake. I was trying all the variants (require, include with _once and without) - result was same.